# Re-render in react-native. Can we optimize the issue i'm facing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

// custom components
import Screen from "../components/Screen";

// context api
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";

function HomeScreen(props) {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  useEffect(() => {
    alert("mount");
    
    return () => {
      alert("unmount");
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <Screen>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("CategoryList", { name: "Mark" })}
      >
        <Text>Mark</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
     
    </Screen>
  );
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

First this component renders and alert message `mount`. Now when I navigate into the CategoryList screen, it successfully navigates into the CategoryList screen but, before navigating into the `CategoryList` screen, this HomeScreen re-renders, alert the messages `mount` and `unmount` both, then only it renders CategoryList screen. My question is if we are navigating into the `CategoryList` screen, then only `CategoryList` screen should render, isn't it ? Why `HomeScreen` re-renders then it goes to `CategoryList` screen. Even from `CategoryList` screen, if I go into another screen, then again it re-rerenders `HomeScreen`, then `CategoryListScreen` then another screen. So, is it the way it works or can we optimize re-renders ?

Navigation structure is like
`App.js`

```
return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
      <Store> //Store is a context provider where the SafeAreaView below has been passed as children props
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
          <NavigationContainer theme={navigationTheme}>
            {user ? <AppNavigator /> : <AuthNavigator />}
          </NavigationContainer>
        </SafeAreaView>
      </Store>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
```

Inside `AppNavigator.js`

```
return (
        <Tab.Navigator
            tabBarOptions={{
                showLabel: false,
                activeBackgroundColor: colors.primary,
                activeTintColor: colors.white
            }}
        >
            <Tab.Screen 
                name="Home" 
                component={HomeNavigator}
                options={{
                    tabBarIcon: ({size, color}) => <MaterialCommunityIcons size={size} color={color} name="home"/>
                }}
            />
           
            
        </Tab.Navigator>
    );
```

Inside `HomeNavigator.js`

```
function HomeNavigator(props) {
  const Stack = createStackNavigator();

  const HomeScreenWrapper = () => {
     return (
       <HomeStore>
         <HomeScreen />
       </HomeStore>
     );
   };

// Given above HomeScreenWrapper is a function which returns HomeScreen component wrapping inside HomeStore which is a context provider for HomeScreen only

  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: colors.primary,
        },
        headerTintColor: colors.white,
      }}
    >
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreenWrapper} />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="CategoryList"
        component={CategoryListScreen}
        options={({ route }) => ({
          title: route.params.name,
          headerBackTitleVisible: false,
        })}
      ></Stack.Screen>

    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

export default HomeNavigator;
```

And to see what's inside HomeScreen, Scroll to the top at first.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read this documentation about [react navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-lifecycle).

> Consider a stack navigator with screens A and B. After navigating to A, its componentDidMount is called. When pushing B, its componentDidMount is also called, but A remains mounted on the stack and its componentWillUnmount is therefore not called.

And this document about [react hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1).

> When exactly does React clean up an effect? React performs the cleanup when the component unmounts. However, as we learned earlier, effects run for every render and not just once. This is why React also cleans up effects from the previous render before running the effects next time.We’ll discuss [why this helps avoid bugs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#explanation-why-effects-run-on-each-update) and [how to opt out of this behavior in case it creates performance issues](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects) later below.

If you want to optimise the navigation read [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/react-native-screens)

> With the advent of react-native-screens, the native screen optimization is brought possible to React Navigation by bringing the native navigation component (UIViewController for iOS, and FragmentActivity for Android). By using react-native-screens, it is possible for each native platform to optimize the memory usage for screens that are under the view stack and also simplify the native node hierarchy. You can take a look at the comparison here to see the performance gain.

Comment: I've gone through the link you provided. I tried the example in the snack given in that link. I understood how the navigation renders. But mine is not working as expected. What happens is, in the above example, the HomeScreen component mounts and alerts the message mount. Now according to the doc, when I navigate from HomeScreen to CategoryList screen, then HomeScreen should not get unmounted but it does in my case and mount again and then navigates to CategoryScreen. After navigating, alert messages be like unmount, mount, and then it navigates to CategoryList screen.

Comment: I cannot help you more because I cannot reproduce the same behavior without looking at the structure of your navigation. When I use your useEffect  the alert only show once.

Comment: I've added the Navigation structure also. So could you try once, that if you could help to figure out what's the issue?

Comment: Yes, I found the issue. The issue was in HomeNavigator. When rendering HomeScreen, I wrapped it inside HomeStore which is the context provider for HomeScreen. But, when I passed just HomeScreen without wrapping inside HomeStore as <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} /> then it is working as expected.